# Streambuilder only showing data from local cache on first launch of app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm using StreamBuilder to stream data from firestore.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream:  _firestore.collection('meals').where('email', isEqualTo: loggedInUser.email).orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots(),
```

If i take out the `.where` section of the stream, it returns all data to the device. Once this has been done, I can then put the `.where` section back in and it works fine. However, it doesn't work straight away. This would suggest the `.where` section only works once the cache already has data. Also, if I add a document using firestore console, it doesn't update the app with the new data. But for some reason it will show all of the updated documents if i remove the `.where` part.

I'm really confused. Any ideas?

Thanks Jason

UPDATE: I've now figured out how to solve this problem. Please see my answer below for how I solved it.

Comment: Will you be setting this stream only once? If so, try using `get()` instead of `snapshots()`. Also, have you tried setting the offline persistence to false? if not, and you don't need it, add this to your code `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false);`. let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Hi @ralemos, thank you for your comment and help - I really appreciate it! I actually figured out the solution to my problem this morning. please see my answer below for how I solved it. I tried to use `get()` and the `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false);` but couldn't get it to work so tried a few other ideas I had and finally got the result I was after. Thank you very much for your help anyway, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer to my problem.

I added `queryUserData();` to the `initState()`. Here's how it looks in the code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    queryUserData();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print('this is a test${loggedInUser.email}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void queryUserData() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    loggedInUser = user;
    final query = await _firestore.collection('meals').orderBy('date', descending: true).where('email', isEqualTo: '${loggedInUser.email}').getDocuments(source: Source.cache);
    var totalEquals = query.documents.length;
    print('$totalEquals records found for this user');

    if (totalEquals >= 1) {
      print(query);
      print('cache has data. Therefore data will now only be read from cache');
    } else {
      print('data will be read from firestore until you have at least 1 meal');
      getFirestoreInitialData();

    }
  }

  void getFirestoreInitialData() async {
    final query = await _firestore.collection('meals').getDocuments();
    print(query);
    print('data still being read from firestore');
  }
```